# SpecialFolder.Personal existing sqlite database

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

On my Xamarin android application i create db path using the "System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal".
I have an existing sqlite database. Where in the project and with what properties must i include the database to be used in the peronal folder?

Comment: You will need to include the existing DB in your project as an Asset, and then at startup copy it to the Personal folder.

Comment: Thank you. How can i copy to the personal folder at startup. Sorry but i'm new to xamarin.

Comment: https://robgibbens.com/deploying-a-database-file-with-a-xamarin-forms-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Xamarin.Essentials` to access your read-only bundle/asset resource and copy it without have to use native platform code or if you are coding within an Xamarin.Android project, you can directly use  `Android.Content`'s Assets

So assuming you have a database in your Android Assets folder:

```
Assets
   db.sqlite
```

#### Xamarin Essentials / NetStd2.0 Code Example:

```
var copyToLocationPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "db.sqlite");
if (!File.Exists(copyToLocationPath))
{
    using (var assetStream = await Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("db.sqlite"))
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(copyToLocationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        await assetStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
var connection = new SqliteConnection(copyToLocationPath);
```

#### Xamarin Android code sample (Directly use `Assets`):

```
var copyToLocationPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "db.sqlite");
if (!File.Exists(copyToLocationPath))
{
    using (var assetStream = Assets.Open("db.sqlite"))
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(copyToLocationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
         await assetStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```