# Is it necessary to use platform-specific file systems or can I use System.IO?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to copy a database file from the resources / assets folder of for iOS and Android, and searched up the methods used by some. [This person](https://medium.com/humbledog/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2c6ec5894510) uses a BinaryReader/Writer for Android while for iOS has File.Copy in use. Can I not just use System.IO.File.Copy for both? I will use Dependency Injection as he does so I can access the specific resource folders for each (unless there is also a cross-platform reference for that?) but I don't see why different file systems need to be used in a Forms project.

Comment: Use can use Xamarin Essentials to access the read-only resources/assets of a Android/iOS app. See the "Xamarin Essentials / NetStd2.0 Code Example" section of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032039/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks heaps for letting me know about that, that's quite helpful.

Comment: neither Resources nor Assets are stored as files